# Plotting Multiple Solve Functions

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

My goal is to plot the functions returned from `Solve` but assigning each solution to a different function.

Here is an example where I do it by hand

```
Solve[a*x^2 + b*x + c == 0, x]


sol1[a_, b_, c_] := (-b - Sqrt[b^2 - 4 a c])/(2 a)

sol2[a_, b_, c_] := (-b + Sqrt[b^2 - 4 a c])/(2 a)

Manipulate[Plot[{sol1[a, b, c], sol2[a, b, c]}, {b, 1, 10}], {a, 1, 10}, {c, 1, 10}]
```

Can this be done all at once without manually defining each function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Manipulate[ Plot[Evaluate[x /. Quiet@Solve[a*x^2 + b*x + c == 0, x]], {b, 1, 10}], 
            {a, 1, 10}, {c, 1, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]